# Invalid Token / does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, face-recognition

I have written a FaceRecognition for a school project. Because I'm new to c# i don't have a clue what to do. Thank you in advance

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FaceDetectionAndRec {
  public partial class Form1 : Form {
    private const string Notepad = @"C:\Windows\Notepad.exe";
    // private const string Jan = @"C:\Users\Jan-Phillip\EXE'S\jan_sm.exe";
    // private const string Marco = @"C:\Users\Jan-Phillip\EXE'S\marco_sm.exe";
    //Declare Variables to use them in all this project 
    MCvFont font = new MCvFont(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 0.6d, 0.6d);
    HaarCascade faceDetected;
    Image<Bgr, Byte> Frame;
    Capture camera;
    Image<Gray, byte> result;
    Image<Gray, byte> TrainedFace = null;
    Image<Gray, byte> grayFace = null;
    List<Image<Gray, byte>> trainingImages = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();
    List<string> labels = new List<string>();
    List<string> Users = new List<string>();
    int Count, NumLables, t;
    string name, names = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //haar cascade is for face detection
        faceDetected = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
        try
        {
            string Labelsinf = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/Faces/Faces.txt");
            string[] Labels = Labelsinf.Split(',');
            //The first Label before, willl be the number of faces saved.
            NumLables = Convert.ToInt16(Labels[0]);
            Count = NumLables;
            string FacesLoad;
            for(int i=1;i<NumLables + 1; i++)
            {
                FacesLoad = "face" + i + ".bmp";
                trainingImages.Add(new Image<Gray, byte>(Application.StartupPath + $"/Faces/{FacesLoad}"));
                labels.Add(Labels[i]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing in the Database");
        }
    }

    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        camera = new Capture();
        camera.QueryFrame();
        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(FrameProcedure);
    }

    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Count = Count + 1;
        grayFace = camera.QueryGrayFrame().Resize(320, 240, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
        MCvAvgComp[][] DetectedFaces = grayFace.DetectHaarCascade(faceDetected, 1.2, 10, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(20, 20));
        foreach (MCvAvgComp f in DetectedFaces[0])
        {
            TrainedFace = Frame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, byte>();
            break;
        }
        TrainedFace = result.Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
        trainingImages.Add(TrainedFace);
        labels.Add(textName.Text);
        File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/Faces/Faces.txt", trainingImages.ToArray().Length.ToString() + ",");
        for (int i = 1; i < trainingImages.ToArray().Length + 1; i++)
        {
            trainingImages.ToArray()[i - 1].Save(Application.StartupPath + "/Faces/face" + i + ".bmp");
            File.AppendAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/Faces/Faces.txt", labels.ToArray()[i - 1] + ",");
        }
        MessageBox.Show(textName.Text + "Added Successfully");

    }

    private void FrameProcedure(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Users.Add("");
        Frame = camera.QueryFrame().Resize(320, 240, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
        grayFace = Frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
        MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetectNow = grayFace.DetectHaarCascade(faceDetected, 1.2, 10, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(20, 20));
        foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetectNow[0])
        {
            result=Frame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, Byte>().Resize(100,100,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
            Frame.Draw(f.rect, new Bgr(Color.Green), 3);
            if(trainingImages.ToArray().Length != 0)
            {
                MCvTermCriteria termCriterias = new MCvTermCriteria(Count, 0.001);
                EigenObjectRecognizer recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(trainingImages.ToArray(), labels.ToArray(), 1500, ref termCriterias);
                name = recognizer.Recognize(result);
                Frame.Draw(name, ref font, new Point(f.rect.X - 2, f.rect.Y - 2), new Bgr(Color.Red));                  

            }               
            Users.Add("");
        }
       // for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        //{
          //  Debug.WriteLine(i);
            //int c = i + 1;
            //if (i == 0)
            //{
       // if (name == "Jan-Phillip")
                //{
                   // Process.Start(Jan);
                    //Debug.WriteLine("Me");
                    //CloseApp();
                //}
        // }
        //    }
        //}
        //else
        //  break;
        // if (i == 0)
        //{
          //  if (name == "marco")
            //{
               // Process.Start(Marco);
                //Debug.WriteLine("Marco");
                //CloseApp();
                //break;
            //};
            //   }
            //}
            else;
                //break;
        }

    cameraBox.Image = Frame;
    names = "";
    Users.Clear();

    private void CloseApp()
    {
        this.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace info? This will ease and increase the ability to help you.